# Microsoft TPL Dataflow for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

As we know [Microsoft TPL Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow) supports platforms:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- .NET for Windows Store apps
- Portable Class Libraries

but there is NO Windows Phone 8 support.

What are the alternatives to replace BufferBlock<>, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supporting TPL Dataflow on Windows Phone is on our backlog. The reason it's not supported is because one of its dependencies hasn't been implemented for Windows Phone yet (namely concurrent collections). However, we believe we could either remove this dependency or port concurrent collections as well.

I've filed a [user voice item](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5236110-microsoft-tpl-dataflow-for-windows-phone) for it. Please share & vote -- it helps us to prioritize this work.

**Update**

I’m happy to announce that we've [released a preview that includes support for Windows Phone 8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow/4.5.16-alpha).

Comment: Depending on how your code is structured you may be able to leverage the Reactive (Rx) framework instead. But it's certainly not a drop in replacement.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is the [Reactive Framework](https://rx.codeplex.com/). It actually is *very* similar to Dataflow. In fact it's so similar, that Dataflow includes [AsObservable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160306%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [AsObserver()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160359%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension methods on its blocks that allow it to interoperate with Reactive Framework. And it's [a NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main) available on Windows Phone.

Comment: Both TPL Dataflow and Rx can be used for similar things, but I'd say that the way you use them is quite different, which means they're suitable for different kinds of problems.